# How can I install the Pspell functions in XAMPP (Windwos/PHP 8)?

Tags: php, apache, xampp, pspell

Unfortunately, all the answers did not help. Is there a way to install the Pspell library in XAMPP (3.3.0 / PHP 8.1.6)?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pspell.php

Or is there any alternative for pspell in PHP?

Comment: According to http://aspell.net/, the function for Windows is no longer maintained. This probably also answers the question.